# JSRender: Render another template from converter or custom tag

Tags: templates, jsrender

I am getting HTML content from a backend service request that might include something (non-JSRender) like this:

```
<div>{{comp:someComponentId}}</div>
```

Or we can receive it as:

```
<div>{{comp someComponentId}}</div>
```

I want to leverage this syntax to use a converter or a tag in JSRender to effectively convert this to:

```
<div>{{include tmpl="someComponentId"/}}</div>
```

Whether the tag/converter does the rendering, or if it can iteratively create the include to have JSRender evaluate it. How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Does this do what you want?

```
<script id="myTmpl" type="text/x-jsrender">
  {{comp someid/}}
</script>

<script id="id1" type="text/x-jsrender">
  what {{:foo}}
</script>

<div id="page"></div>

<script>
  $.views.tags("comp", {
    render:  function(id) {
      return $("#"+id).render(this.tagCtx.view.data);
    }
  });

  var myTmpl = $.templates("#myTmpl"),
    data = { someid: "id1", foo: "FOO" },
    html = myTmpl(data);
  $("#page").html(html);
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll give it a try. I am doing this server-side, so hopefully the following will work: 
return jsrender.render[id].render(this.tagCtx.view.data);

Comment: There's two problems I am facing. The content I get can come as {{comp:someid}} or {{comp someid}}.  The first problem is, as a tag, this breaks because it has no / closing slash. The second problem is, someid IS the id, and it breaks, because it doesn't have quotes around it.

Comment: If you cannot make it render out valid syntax, within a template, then it will clearly fail. You can do `var templateString = $("#myTmpl").text()`, then massage the string to have closing slashes (`templateString2`) and then `myTmpl = $.templates(templateString2)`. By declaring the tag.render() method as above then someid is passed in as function(id) and you don't need to add quotes. Why would that break? It works above.... In this approach you are not creating a template string, `{{include tmpl="someid"...}}`. The above should be semantically equivalent to doing that...

Comment: I am able to have the service request changed to get the fragment in the format of <div>{{comp:'someComponentId'}}</div> so that it will work. Without the quotes, someComponentId is treated as a property name, not a string, which is why it breaks. And I can't do $('#myTmpl").text(), because it's on the server. Plus, we can't afford to do a lot of string manipulation on the sever for performance reasons. But thanks for your help! I've got something that works, now.

Comment: Your original question was too succint (for me at least) and I had thought you were *wanting* to get the id from a property name, someComponentId - which is why my example code above had `{{comp someid/}}` and `data = { someid: "id1", ...}`. I follow now what you meant by "someid IS the id" -  but we were previously at cross purposes in the discussion...